# Sort directories in bash

Tags: bash, perl

I want to go through the content of each directory and select the files within each directory randomly the code is working fine. However when it is traversing through directories, It doesn't process them in a sorted way. For example, I have directories named as `Label_1`, `Label_2`, `Label_3`,..., `Label_83`,
but when the script is running it is echoing `Label_1`, `Label_2`, `Label_10`,... 
I want this echoing to happen in a sorted way like after `Label_2` should be `Label_3` not `label_10`as it affects the final result in train.list and test.list. Is there anyway how I can sort these directories so that it would be written in the output files in the sorted way?

```
#!/bin/bash
> train.list
> test.list
COUNT=-1
for folder in $1/*
do
        echo $folder
        COUNT=$[$COUNT + 1]
        for imagesFolder in "$folder"/*
        do
                if ( (( ( RANDOM % $2 )  ))  > 1 ); then
                        echo "$imagesFolder" $COUNT >> train.list
                else
                        echo "$imagesFolder" $COUNT >> test.list
                fi
                done
done
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to rename directories before with `000` integer prefix :

```
find . -type d -name '*Label_*' -exec \
    rename 's/Label_(\d+)/sprintf "Label_%.03d", $1/e' {} \;
```

[image: warning] **There are other tools with the same name which may or may not be able to do this, so be careful.**

If you run the following command (`GNU`)

```
$ file "$(readlink -f "$(type -p rename)")"
```

and you have a result that contains `Perl script, ASCII text executable` and not containing `ELF`, then this seems to be the right tool =)

If not, to make it the default (usually already the case) on `Debian` and derivative like `Ubuntu` :

```
$ sudo update-alternatives --set rename /path/to/rename
```

Replace `/path/to/rename` to the path of your `perl rename` executable.

---

If you don't have this command, search your package manager to install it or [do it manually](https://web.archive.org/web/20130625192518/https://metacpan.org/module/RMBARKER/File-Rename-0.20/rename.PL) (no deps...)

---

<sub><sup>This tool was originally written by Larry Wall, the Perl's dad.</sup></sub>

Comment: The `rename` command that is part of the util-linux package -- won't.

Comment: Yes, as explained deeply

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is to use `sort` :

```
for folder in $(printf '%s\n' $1/*/ | sort -V); do
    ...
```